# Java generic interface in collection

Tags: java, generics

Can anybody explain me why I get an error only when creating B in the following code:

```
public class factory {

    public <T> void createA(List<I<T>> c) {
        A a = new A(c);//warning here
    }

    public <T> void createB(List<I<T>> c) {
        B b = new B(c);//error here: The constructor B(List<I<T>>) is undefined
    }
}

interface I<T> {
}


class B implements I<Integer> {

    public B(List<I<?>> c) {
    }
}

class A<T> implements I<T> {

    public A(List<I<?>> c) {
    }
}
```

B class is generic and A is not, but I have no idea why it matters in that case.

Comment: I hope you have imported `List`. If not, I think that's the error.

Comment: What error message are you getting, exactly?

Comment: I ommited import statements it's not an issue here. I'm getting: "The constructor B(List<I<T>>) is undefined"
as I wrote in comment.

Comment: Uhm, are you having pleasure doing generics torture? ;) What do you really want to achieve ultimately?

Comment: `A a = new A(c)` is a raw expression so it erases all generics from the A class and you don't have a compile error. If you use generics properly you will get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public B(List<I<?>> c) {
}
```

The `?` is the [*unknown type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). It is not a wild card for any other type. The compiler tells the truth, there is no constructor for the type `List<I<T>>` (`T` is not `?`)

It doesn't really work for the other method too. You simply exchanged the compile error by a "unchecked conversion" warning. Because class `A` is parametized, you'd have to call it like that:

```
public <T> void createA(List<I<T>> c) {
    A<T> a = new A<T>(c);
}
```

And voilà, say hello to the same error.

Comment: But then, why does this work? Just add this to class B: `static class B<ASDAS> implements I<Integer> {` Constructor is still the same, but no more compiler error.

Comment: Now you get "unchecked conversion" warnings. Yes, it compiles. But it's still not possible if you want to avoid the unchecked conversions.

Comment: If you do a proper constructor call for the other method (`new A<T>(c)` then you see the same error there.

Comment: that's an answer I expected - new A(c) isn't proper invokation of constructor for generic A class and taht cause warrning instead of error. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is not correct. `T` *can be* `?` by capture, but capture only applies to the top level type parameter. So if the parameter is `I<?>` and you pass an `I<T>`, then you *can* pass it. But you cannot pass `List<I<T>>` to `List<I<?>>` because it's different; capture doesn't apply because the `?` is deeper than the top level.

Comment: And about the other method, The reason it doesn't error is because generics is turned off by using a raw type.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is a generic class, which means that when you use `A` by itself, it is a raw type. When you use a raw type, you turn off all the generics for its methods and constructors. So for example, the following will compile:

```
A a = new A(new ArrayList<String>());
```

`B` is not a generic class, so using `B` by itself is not a raw type, and does not turn off generics.